# I downloaded ue4 and it is occupying a lot of space

Tags: ssd, storage, windows-11, disc, space

[this is the space after deleting intermediate folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQl0H.jpg) I heard unreal engine 4.27 occupies only 47 gb of disc space but in
my pc it occupied 91.4gb and now only 47gb of free space left. What to do? I don't want to reinstall the whole thing which is really hectic

Comment: What exactly is your question? It sounds like you have UE4 installed twice. Are you sure the single install is using 91.4 GB? Can you provide us more details, or even screenshots, that can clarify your question?

Comment: in this, the total space occupied by the binaries folder is 28.9gb, program files>>epic games>>ue_4.27>>engine>>plugins and the plugins folder ,
program files>>epic games>>ue_4.27>>engine>>plugins occupied 33.5gb

Comment: program files>>epic games>>ue_4.27>>engine>>source occupied 8.31gb

Comment: You are viewing the Properties of `Epic Games` which is the same folder that applications installed through the Epic Launcher is installed to, are you certain that the properties of UE4, is actually taking 91.4 GB?  *Please provide screenshots instead of a comment by editing your queston.*

Comment: in the previous comment, it was engine>>binaries folder for 28.9 gb and not plugins there

Comment: Do you have any additional plugins that are outside of the base installation of UE4?  Editing your question, instead of unformatted commentary, would be very helpful.

Comment: Please put all of the information in your clarifying comments into your question

Answer (score 0):

> "What do you do?"

You buy a bigger hard drive and then use cloning software like clonezilla(or etc) to move all your data to a bigger drive.

Answer (score 0):

Check This article
https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/oortvx/unreal_engine_20gb_install_ends_up_consuming_over/

This is my solution, it should help

"It seems like fake size is reserved. This solution worked for me.
The Engine 4.27 and 5.0.3 in my case reserved the maximum size when I install the engine with only the engine checked, for engine 5.0.3, it toke 113.7GB, click on the small arrow under the engine > choose "Options" > add any new feature, In my case I added "Starter contents"> click "Apply" > wait until finish installing

the size dropped from 113.7 GB to 31.2GB"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1146820)